# A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.9/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.9.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.9/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.9.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assemble Debug'...                              4.7s
Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the version you want is `1.9.0`. If it is semantically versioned, the `.0` appended to it is contextually important.

Google and Maven repos don't have a version `1.9`, they have `1.9.0`.

Comment: tanks issue solved